# Synchronize arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

Help me please but just started to learn php and already here is an obscure task, arrays in php have a slightly different structure than in other programming languages so I can not fully understand what and how to do in a task.

Create 2 Arrays:
cities (3), districts
areas, streets, houses.
Display the data with the synchronization table
[image]

Comment: unclear please be more precise

Comment: Seems is unclear for the same op :)

Comment: So I also can not fully understand the task

Comment: @user221117 I'd recommend take some time to get a grasp of what your task is, then come back and ask a new question about what you need help with. We're happy to help any programming related problems, but interpreting questions is unfortunately off topic.